# Adding Pandas series values Pandas dataframe values

Tags: pandas, addition

I have a dataframe and a series

```
A   B  C
1   3  4
2   5  6

s = df['A']
```

I have to add `df + df['A]`
All column of df should add values of df['A'] depending on index.

Comment: Use `df = df.add(df['A'], axis=0)`

Comment: @jpp - Why answering if dupe?

Comment: @Ajith, I posted a new answer on the dup, just so you know.